# C pthread written correctly but does not work at all; why?

Tags: c, ubuntu, pthreads

I am studying threads in c for an exam and I am trying to solve the following exercise, given by the professor as a training:

> Write a program that accepts an integer number 'n' from command line and creates n threads; then waits their termination.

I tried to solve this, but it seems not working for some reason.
This is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void *StampaThread(void *arg){
   char *ret;
   strcpy(ret,"Fine thread");
   printf("thread %p scritto!\n", arg);
   pthread_exits(ret);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){

pthread_t thread[1000];
void *ret;

if(argc!=2){
   perror("Argomenti insufficienti o in eccesso!\n");
}
else
{
   int n=atoi(argv[0]);
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,StampaThread,&i)!=0){
         perror("problema nella creazione dei thread\n");
         exit(1);
      }
      if((pthread_join(thread[i],&ret))!=0){
         perror("problema nella attesa dei thread\n");
         exit(3);
      }
      printf("%s",(char *)ret);
   }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: argv[0] is the name of you program.

Comment: Also you are doing create0/join0, create1/join1, etc but I think the prof wants you to create all of them first before waiting.

Comment: Voting to close because shows no effort at debugging.

Comment: @kaylum So i have to make them work in two different cycles, did I understood?

Comment: @stark That's the answer. And he apparently knows that: `if(argc!=2)`

Comment: Side-tip: use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. It allows you to spot errors.

Comment: If by "cycle" you mean "loop" then yes. One loop to create all the threads and after that another loop to join all the treads.

Comment: I have done all the corrections suggested by all of you and seems to work but it doesn't create all the threads: in point of fact, it creates only one and then gives a Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Comment: `char *ret; strcpy(ret,"Fine thread");` That won't work as `ret` is uninitialised. That's probably the cause of the seg fault.

Comment: Please post a copy paste of the actual code, not something you made up just now. `int main(int argc,char** argc)` will obviously not compile.

Comment: @kaylum It works now, I will post the answer; just in case someone need in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the contribution given by some developers on the first comment section, I have found the correct code to solve the exercise; in addiction, I added some code to show up integers, instead of memory location, used by the procedure.
The code is the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

void *StampaThread(void *arg){
   char *ret=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char *));
   strcpy(ret,"Fine thread");
   printf("thread %d scritto!\n", *(int *)arg);
   free(arg);
   pthread_exits(ret);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){

pthread_t thread[1000];
void *ret;

if(argc!=2){
   perror("Argomenti insufficienti o in eccesso!\n");
}
else
{
   int n=strtol(argv[1],NULL,10);
   int i;
   int *arg;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      arg=malloc(sizeof(*arg));
      *arg=i;
      if(pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,StampaThread,arg)!=0){
         perror("problema nella creazione dei thread\n");
         exit(1);
      }
   }
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      if((pthread_join(thread[i],&ret))!=0){
         perror("problema nella attesa dei thread!\n");
         exit(3);
      }
    }
    printf("%s",(char *)ret);
}
return 0;
}
```